# How to connect Janusgraph to Cassandra using two-way TLS

Tags: ssl, cassandra, janusgraph

I have a cassandra cluster set up to require two-way TLS based on the following parameters:

```
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    require_client_auth: true
```

I also have keystore and truststore set and their passwords. I can connect with cqlsh from my client machine.

I am trying to configure my janusgraph based application to connect to this cluster, but I don't see which janusgraph configuration options to use for this. I am looking at https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/config-ref.html#_storage_cassandra_ssl_truststore and I have set all three of the `storage.cassandra.ssl.*` properties, but this only gives me one-way TLS (works if `require_client_auth` is false). Is there some other setting I'm missing, or is this something janusgraph doesn't support?